# tsql datetime vs int query performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

Would it make any sense to store a datetime as an int or bigint for performance purposes. Wondering if indexing/querying the integer column would yield better performance than a datetime column.

If there is a performance difference does anyone know if it is substantial, or relatively negligible.

Comment: Do not make non-standard design decisions to deal with a performance issue that does not exist. This is known as premature optimization and almost always results in worse performance.

Comment: I agree with you, wise advice. In this case we're setting up a datawarehouse and we often query against dates. So the DBA is considering using a bigint column as well as a date column, because the int may help performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the time from client side and storing it in the database that would come in different formats.

In SQL Server you can set only single collation for datetime, so it is ideal to store the value as bigint in `UNIX time format` ( i.e number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 )

In case the time is relative and only generated on the machine where SQL server is residing , the date time would make sense, but store it in `UTC` so that it is easy to convert to other time zones for reporting or display purpose.

The conversion from Unix time to Date time for display purpose should not be of much performance impact.

Comment: would you recommend also keeping a datetime column present for logical processing such as using dateadd() etc.?

Comment: the logical processing can be done in the stored procedure or view, so only storing int is fine.

Comment: -1 for recommending date/time values to be stored as `bigint`, +1 for storing as UTC

Comment: @BryanEargle, what if client sends the time in different time format assume London client sending to US, will conversion need to be done on the Server side to represent Current SQL Server date time collation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx). Any storage benefit realized using an `int` datatype will be negated by the conversion and parsing code required to display, aggregate, or compare values.

Comment: Not just negated but actually worse. Doing this type of on the fly cast/convert will kill their performance.

Comment: What if both where present, a datetime field and a int smartdate key

Comment: Why add another column that's not needed? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What would be the point of the int? A join isn't going to be any slower on a datetime datatype than an int. Keep in mind that internally datetime is stored as a numeric so it can be retrieved fast.

Comment: yea that's actually the nature of the question, if what you say is true, that joining and querying against a datetime vs an int is negligible then I think we have the answer, which is just keep the datetime.